# Создание Web приложений на С++

Tags: книги, c++

Откуда можно начать изучение создания Web приложений на С++ с нуля? Посоветуйте мне пожалуйста книгу, откуда я с нуля смогу изучить его. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: не надо создавать web приложения на С++. Он для этого совсем не предназначен...

Comment: тогда на C#? А на счет него что подскажете?

Comment: [ASP .NET MVC][1] для C#

[1]: http://www.asp.net/mvc

Answer (score 1):

Книг не подскажу, но поделюсь ссылочкой на фрэймворк для разработки web-приложений на C++. Называется он [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt), структура очень похожа на структуру [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/).

А вообще мне кажется что другие инструменты (Python/Django, RubyOnRails, PHP в конце концов) будут гораздо удобнее для веб-разработки.